# ReactJS/FP difference between state and this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

As the title asks, what is the difference between using "state" and "this" inside a ReactJS component? If I console log the component's "this", the state and properties declared using "this" appear at the same "level" within the object.

"state" just seems like an additional property to wrap component properties? If I wanted to pass "state" as a prop to another component surely passing "this" should suffice?

Eg.:

```
state = {
  isPastDelay: false,
};

componentDidMount () {
  this._delayTimer = setTimeout(() => () {
    console.log('Timeout');
  }, 200);

  console.log(this);
}
```

Why not just declare `_delayTimer` inside state?

Or is the `this._delayTimer` acting like a "private" property?

I would also think `_delayTimer` should be declared outside of `componentDidMount()` and only assigned a value inside the method.

Comment: These are very different things. You should read about `this` in javascript -- it means different things in different contexts: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this You can think of `state` as the state of the data bound to a component at a given point in time.

Comment: state is used to trigger re-render of the component. In your case, you could probably use state for _delayTimer but it would be pointless as you don't want it to provoke any rerender, that's why theses kinds of property are not associated to the state

Comment: @Axnyff now that's starting to make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**State**](http://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) is related to ReactJS. It is like a container for the data. A *State* can be used by the component where it is declared(container component) and it's child components. We should always try to make our state as simple as possible and minimize the number of stateful components.

Whereas, [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is related to JavaScript. `this` is related to the context. In most of the places `this` is related to a function and how it was called. Hence, it's value may be different each time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

[*state*](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) property is needed for instance method *setState*.
When you need to change a state of your component you call *setState* and it changes state property.
It is a convention.

```
class App extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        ticks: 0
    };
}

componentWillMount = () => {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.setState((state) => { return { ticks: state.ticks + 1 } }), 500);
};

componentWillUnmount = () => {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.ticks}
        </div>);
}
```

}

Comment: So is "state" a convention for ReactJS as the setState method is obviously not available to plain JavaScript FP? The reason I ask is because I've seen developers using state in plain JavaScript as-well. I'm guessing then that state is a FP convention which ReactJS has just extended on?

Comment: setState is a part of a standard React.Component class. It isn't part of JavaScript.

Comment: When you saw developers using *state* variable in plain JS it was because of different semantics of *this* keyword depending on the context of execution

Comment: See the details regarding *this* semantics here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: If you update your answer to include that state within ReactJS also triggers re-renders and that it's not necessary to include _delayTimer as that would trigger unnecessary re-renders I can tick this answer.

Comment: Wancieho, I am not sure what is your real scenario so I give you two options to chose. Consider these samples:

1. fetches data from the remote server to update state
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7bmYR3RWZZ/

2. uses timer to update recurrently:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gz2JgdhtHM/

Comment: Or consider even simpler example in the updated answer